# Rails current_page? versus controller.controller_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action, current-page

I'm implementing `current_page?` in a view to test if the current controller and action is equal to a certain value, however it won't return true when on that controller/action combination.

```
- if current_page?(:controller => 'pages', :action => 'main') 
# doesn't return true when on that controller/action combination
```

The only way it is working is if I use a bit more verbose method like so:

```
- if controller.controller_name == 'pages' && controller.action_name == 'main'
# this works just fine
```

Is my syntax wrong or is there something else happening here?  Is there a better way of doing this, such as setting a BOOL or is this the proper way?

The end goal is to only show a certain header on the main landing page while showing a different header on all other pages.

**Edit**: Relevant output from `rake routes`:

```
pages_main GET  /pages/main(.:format)  {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"main"}

root   /(.:format)   {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"main"}
```

Also, this is the server output upon rendering:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-03 16:54:40 -0500
Processing by PagesController#main as HTML
Rendered pages/main.html.haml within layouts/application (203.8ms)
```

Comment: Your action method names should not start with a capital letter, by convention.

Comment: yeah, 'Main' should be 'main'. see if that makes a difference

Comment: Convention aside, it unfortunately didn't make a difference.  Thanks for the suggestion all the same!

Comment: Please include the output of `rake routes`.

Comment: @jdl: Added the relevant output (there was a lot, so I didn't paste the others)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`current_page?(root_path)` works fine.

But I can't make it work with `:controller` and `:action`

It seems the helper expects a string, so:

```
current_page?(url_for(:controller => 'pages', :action => 'main'))
```

works fine too.

Weird contradiction with [the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F).

Comment: It is strange that the standard way doesn't work, but I'll go with `current_page?(root_path)` for now since it's nice and short.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: `current_page?(root_path)` should be true only when `"/"` for current path, but not for `"/pages/main"`  I guess. Is it any wrong to have `if controller_name == 'pages' && action_name == 'main'` here?

Comment: In my case I have a `Home#index` controller assigned to root which only redirects to, in this case, `Pages#main`. Then I use `current_page?(main_page_path)` assuming you created that route in `config/routes.rb`

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when I had 2 routes that were very similar. Check this out:

```
match '/galleries/sales' => 'galleries#sales', :as => 'gallery_sales'
match '/galleries/sales/:id' => 'galleries#sales', :as => 'gallery_category_sales'
```

My controller action handled the output depending on params, and I originally did this b/c I didn't want duplication.

When I did:

```
current_page?(:controller => 'galleries', :action => 'sales', :id => id)
```

It didn't return true when it should have, so I created a different route and action and it worked fine.