# Rails current_page? "fails" when method is POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a really simple problem. I have a page of reports and each report has its own tab. I'm using `current_page?` to determine which tab should be highlighted. When I submit any report, `current_page?` doesn't seem to work anymore, apparently because the request method is `POST`.

Is this the intended behavior of `current_page?` I have a hard time imagining why that would be the case. If it is, how do people normally get around this problem?

Here's an example of a `current_page?` call:

`<li><%= link_to "Client Retention", reports_client_retention_path, :class => current_page?(reports_client_retention_path) ? "current" : "" %></li>`

Comment: Can you add the error to your question, including how you are using current_page?

Comment: I edit my question to include my `current_page?` call. I'm not getting an error. It just returns false.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All right, it looks like I figured out the answer to my own question about 5 minutes after putting up a bounty. It looks like `current_page?` will always return false on `POST`.

Here's the source code for `current_page?`:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb, line 588
def current_page?(options)
  unless request
    raise "You cannot use helpers that need to determine the current "                  "page unless your view context provides a Request object "                  "in a #request method"
  end

  return false unless request.get?

  url_string = url_for(options)

  # We ignore any extra parameters in the request_uri if the
  # submitted url doesn't have any either. This lets the function
  # work with things like ?order=asc
  if url_string.index("?")
    request_uri = request.fullpath
  else
    request_uri = request.path
  end

  if url_string =~ %r^\w+:\/\//
    url_string == "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request_uri}"
  else
    url_string == request_uri
  end
end
```

I don't really understand why they would have gone out of their way to make `current_page?` work only for `GET` requests, but at least now I know that that's the way it is.

Comment: You should probably accept your answer, and remove the bounty.

Comment: I can't do that yet because, as you can see, I only answered the question one hour ago.

Comment: If anyone else is having the same frustration I had, I found a workaround to the `current_page?` "problem" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186613/rails-current-page-versus-controller-controller-name

Comment: I also was interested in this restriction, so I found the commit where it was introduced - https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fddf7ea1c1e520f33fa26fe340f3fc107bcc95c8. Unfortunately, it does not explain much.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a new `current_path?` method in your `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def current_path?(*paths)
  return true if paths.include?(request.path)
  false
end
```

Pass in one or more paths and it returns true if any match the user's current path:

```
current_path?('/user/new')
current_path?(root_path)
current_path?(new_user_path, users_path '/foo/bar')
```

Or, you can create a new `current_request?` helper method to check the Rails controller + action:

```
def current_request?(*requests)
  return true if requests.include?({
    controller: controller.controller_name,
    action: controller.action_name
  })
  false
end
```

Pass in one or more controller + action and it returns true if any match the user's current request:

```
current_request?(controller: 'users', action: 'new')
current_request?({controller: 'users', action: 'new'}, {controller: 'users', action: 'create'})
```

**==UPDATE==**

Ok, I decided to make using `current_request?` a little less verbose by not requiring that you type out the controller when you are trying to match multiple actions:

```
def current_request?(*requests)
  requests.each do |request|
    if request[:controller] == controller.controller_name
      return true if request[:action].is_a?(Array) && request[:action].include?(controller.action_name)
      return true if request[:action] == controller.action_name
    end
  end
  false
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
current_request?(controller: 'users', action: ['new', 'create'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem when using `POST`. My solution was to do something like this

```
def menu_item link_text, link_path
  link_class = (request.original_url.end_with? link_path) ? 'active' : ''
  content_tag :li, link_to(link_text, link_path), class: link_class
end
```

where `link_path` is just `url_for(action: 'action', controller: 'controller')`