# Use content_for with src attribute of a script tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, content-for

I figured out how to use `content_for` for some elements, for example `<title>`:

```
<% content_for :title, "Hi, I'm #{@user.username}" %>
```

But I can't seem to get it working when I need to inject a `<script>` tag with `src` attribute. I.e. this code:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

How can I use `content_for` to place a script tag (with `src` attribute) in the `head` of a page?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from another forum

Add this to your head

```
<%= yield :whatever_name_you_want %>
```

And add this to your template/view:

```
<% content_for :whatever_name_you_want do %>
   <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<% end %>
```