# Ruby on Rails get URL and use it within an if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, if-statement, get

I have a ruby on rails application, and want to display an image on the index page depending on what the URL is. If the url is: `localhost:3000/products/multi_find` I do not want to show the image, if it is anything else I do want it to be shown.

Is their a way I can retrieve the url and store it in a variable to run an `<& if statement like: if url != localhost:3000/products/multi_find &><%= image tag "test.png", :size => "15x18" %> <% end %>`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Didn't get your need..

Comment: I want to know how to get it so that the application knows what the url is and that this is stored in a variable to determine whether to display an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those solutions worked, this did:

```
<% if request.original_url == 'http://localhost:3000/products/multi_find' %>
    <%= image tag "test.png", :size => "15x18" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you must think in terms of routing rules, not URLs. An URL is nothing else than the result of a routing directive.

Therefore, `/products/multi_find` can be expressed in terms of `action`, `controller` and parameters.

With that in mind, you can use the [`current_page?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) helper to check if the current URL matches the route you expect, if it does then ignore the image.

Comment: Thank you, so would it be <% if current_page? != localhost:3000/products/multi_find %>

Answer (score 0):

You can even use rails "action_name" and "controller_name" helper methods to get the job done.

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to ruby, can you show me how I'd use that please? Like where it goes, what the if statement would look like

Comment: you can refer this tag, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186613/rails-current-page-versus-controller-controller-name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% unless current_page?('/products/multi_find') %>
  <%= image tag "test.png", :size => "15x18" %>
<% end %>
```